# Autopopulate Text based on control value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a table that has a few simple fields. Transaction ID (TID populated with Autonumber), Date, Transaction Status (Integer), Status, and Notes. Status is a lookup field that pulls its values from another table. It shows the text of the status but stores the status ID as an integer. Notes is a memo field. Usually when we have a certain status, the Note field generally has the same text. It does change often enough that I can't have Status and Notes linked. However, I want the Notes field in my form for this table to autopopulate with the most common entries based on the status chosen when adding a new TID. Let me give you an example.

I create a new TID. I enter the date then the Status. At this point in time when I leave the Status control, I want the notes field to autopopulate with a default based on the status. Here is the code I have created but it's not working. I have tried replacing the Case number, i.e. Case 132, with "132" and the status text "Closed" but none of them work either. Any assistance would be helpful.

```
Private Sub Status_Ctrl_LostFocus()
    Dim NoteDetail As String
    Dim OffStat As Integer
    OffStat = Me.Status_Ctrl.Value
    If Me!Details = Null Or Me!Details = "" Then
        Select Case OffStat

            Case 132 'Offer Closed
                NoteDetail = "Offer Closed."

            Case 133 'Offer Failed
                If Me.Parent!EMCust_Ctrl = 32 Then
                    NoteDetail = "Offer rejected. EM returned to Buyer."
                Else
                    NoteDetail = "Offer rejected."
                End If

            Case 134 'Offer Accepted
                NoteDetail = "Offer Accepted."

            Case 164 'Offer Presented
                NoteDetail = "Offer Presented. EM held for acceptance."
        End Select

        With Me!Details_Ctrl
            .Value = NoteDetail
        .SetFocus
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: is the code falling into the select case statement?  It look like it may not go there based on the if statement.

Comment: Set a break point on the `OffStat =` line and step through the code one line at a time with the `F8` key.  This condition is suspect: `If Me!Details = Null` ... use `If IsNull(Me!Details)` if you want to check whether `Me!Details` **is** Null.  (It can never be **equal** to Null because nothing can ever be **equal** to Null, not even another Null.)

Comment: Thank you HansUp. It was the Null that was giving me problems. It works just fine now. Could you put your post as an answer to my question so I can give you the credit for answering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a break point on the OffStat = line and step through the code one line at a time with the F8 key. This condition is suspect: If Me!Details = Null ... use If IsNull(Me!Details) if you want to check whether Me!Details is Null. (It can never be equal to Null because nothing can ever be equal to Null, not even another Null.) –  HansUp Nov 22 at 20:07